# Flask can't redirect me to home page, it just gives me the html code as response

Tags: python, flask

I'm building a login with flask and flask-login, and the authentication works perfectly. When a user is authenticated, he should be automatically redirected to the home page (which is unavailable for a not-logged user). The issue is that `flask.redirect` function just returns me the html code of the home page instead of redirecting to that page. I see the html code in the response object inside the browser console. How can I solve?
Here it is the relevant code:

```
@app.route('/home')
@flask_login.login_required
def home():
    return render_template('home.html')


@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    if(request.method == 'GET'):
        return render_template('login.html')

    email = request.form['email']
    passwd = request.form['passwd']
    data = getUsersData()
    for key in data:
        if(email == data[key]['email'] and passwd == data[key]['pass']):
            user = User()
            user.id = email
            flask_login.login_user(user, remember=True)
            next = request.args.get('next')
            if(next):
                return redirect(next)
            else:
                return redirect(url_for('home'))

    abort(401) # if inside the for, it can't find valid username and password
```

I would like that when the authentication succeeded, the browser redirects me to `localhost:10000/home`

EDIT:
[The terminal log with both GET and POST request to `/home`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FkRXB.png)

EDIT 2:
[The response object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CwIB3.png)

Comment: Note: `next` is a built in function. You should choose another name.

Comment: @LaurentLAPORTE I used `next` exactly in the same way of [this snippet](https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#login-example)

Comment: @Alessio, this might still give you unexpected behavior, as @laurent suggested, `next` is a python builtin, use something else. The example should not use this as a variable name. replace with next_url to see if odd behavior persists.

Comment: @GG_Python, I tried to replace`next` with `next_url`, but the result is exactly the same as before

Comment: Add `methods=['GET', 'POST']` to the `/home` because when you login, the current method is POST, and, without specification, the route only accept GET.

Comment: @LaurentLAPORTE Still not working... In the terminal I have the log of all http request, and the call to `/home` returns always status code 200, with both `GET` and `POST` requests. I get the html code of the destination page, but the redirect still doesn't work... It's so strange

Comment: Could you retry without the decoration: `@flask_login.login_required` (with the `methods=['GET', 'POST']`, please?

Comment: @LaurentLAPORTE also without the decorator, it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

If I look at your screen copy, you have something like this:

```
"POST /login HTTP/1.1" 302 -
"POST /home HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

*note:* you can have exit code 302 or 307, which is approximately the same: a redirection.

So, the redirection from `/login` to  `/home` works. No error here.

You said:

> The issue is that `flask.redirect` function just returns me the HTML code of the home page instead of redirecting to that page.

But this is exactly what you implement here:

```
@app.route('/home')
@flask_login.login_required
def home():
    return render_template('home.html')
```

So, I think there is an ambiguity: what do you call "home page"? Is it the page of the `/home` route, or an "index.html" page which can be the page of the "/" route?

Comment: My home page is the page `home.html`, that I pass as argument to `render_template` function inside the `/home` route. What should I write into `/home` route to make the redirect to `localhost:10000/home` ?

Comment: Do you mean you want to redirect to another web site? What is `localhost:10000`? On which port to you serve your main app pages?

Comment: `localhost:10000` is the port in which my server is serving the API. The login is served in `localhost:10000/login` while the home page is server in `localhost:10000/home` and I want to be redirected to `localhost:10000/home` if the login is completed with success

Comment: Maybe this kind of redirect can be done only client side using javascript?

Comment: The redirection already work, so I don't understand your problem. Sorry, I give up.

Comment: Just for explaination: you're right, the redirect works, but I need to change the location. I need to display the home page on my browser. Now I just get the html code, but the page is not displayed on the screen.  
EDIT: Something similar to `header` in php

Comment: This is not a redirection pb. Your page isn't well-rendered. Can you Edit and post the HTML code you get in your browser. You can inspect your request on your browser and see the heading. I'm sure you don't have HTML. Also, show us (a fragment) of your `'home.html'`.

Comment: I've added the screen of the response object... the html is inside `responseText`

Comment: Give the responseText please

Comment: Thank you for your time, but I solved using `window.location.replace(url)` from the client side.

Comment: @Alessio having the same issue, what exactly did you replace with ```window.location.replace(url)```?